# Nullpointer at Upnavigation android

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, menuitem, up-navigation

I would like to send two extras via intent, when upnavigation at actionbar is clicked. At the manifest parent activity is declared, at OnCreate at the second activity `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` is set. But the parent activity needs an intent value to work (citySave). I´ve tried a lot, but I don´t get it working, that the upnavigation sends intent values to the parent activity (R.id.home).

I´ven´t added the whole code from second activity, because it would be too much signs. I use at second activity 2 fragments, which are defined static. I don´t know, if this has anything to do with the problem.

Second activity:

```
public class RouteView extends ActionBarActivity {

    Integer citySave;
    String cityTitle;
    Integer routeSave;
    String routeTitel;
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 2;
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<RowItem> pois;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_view);
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        citySave = b.getInt("stadt");
        cityTitle = b.getString("titel_stadt");
        routeSave = b.getInt("route");
        routeTitel = b.getString("titel_route");
        b.putString("titel_route",routeTitel);
        b.putInt("route", routeSave);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //RouteItemFragment fragobj = new RouteItemFragment();
        //fragobj.setArguments(b);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        setTitle("Route:" + " " + routeTitel);


public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(RouteView.this, RouteChooseActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("stadt", citySave);
        b.putString("titel_stadt", cityTitle);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("stadt", citySave);
        b.putInt("route", routeSave);
        b.putString("route_titel",routeTitel);
        finish();
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        citySave = b.getInt("stadt");
        routeSave = b.getInt("route");
        routeTitel = b.getString("route_titel");

    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("stadt", citySave);
                b.putString("titel_stadt", cityTitle);
                upIntent.putExtras(b);
                //startActivity(upIntent);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_stadt:
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_stadt);
                Intent stadt = new Intent(RouteView.this, StadtActivity.class);
                startActivity(stadt);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_route:
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_choose);
                Intent route = new Intent(RouteView.this, RouteChooseActivity.class);
                route.putExtra("stadt", citySave);
                route.putExtra("titel_stadt", cityTitle);
                startActivity(route);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_help:
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);
                Intent help = new Intent(RouteView.this, Help.class);
                startActivity(help);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_exit:
                moveTaskToBack(true);
                System.exit(0);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Parent activity:

```
    public class RouteChooseActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

        Integer citySave;
        Integer routeSave;
        String cityTitle;
        ListView listView;
        List<RowItem> cities;
        CityParser parser = new CityParser();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_choose);
            Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
            citySave = b.getInt("stadt");
            cityTitle = b.getString("titel_stadt");
            TextView headingRoute = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.routeTitel);
            headingRoute.setText(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.route_text)) + " " + cityTitle + " aus:");
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listRoute);
   if (citySave.equals(1)) {
            try {
                cities = parser.parse(getAssets().open("route_passau.xml"));
                CityListViewAdapter adapter = new CityListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_items, (ArrayList<RowItem>) cities);
                Collections.sort(cities, new Comparator<RowItem>() {
                    public int compare(RowItem s1, RowItem s2) {
                        return s1.getTitle().compareTo(s2.getTitle());
                    }
                });
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (citySave.equals(2)) {
            try {
                cities = parser.parse(getAssets().open("route_bamberg.xml"));
                CityListViewAdapter adapter = new CityListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_items, (ArrayList<RowItem>) cities);
                Collections.sort(cities, new Comparator<RowItem>() {
                    public int compare(RowItem s1, RowItem s2) {
                        return s1.getTitle().compareTo(s2.getTitle());
                    }
                });
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (citySave.equals(3)) {
            try {
                cities = parser.parse(getAssets().open("route_augsburg.xml"));
                CityListViewAdapter adapter = new CityListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_items, (ArrayList<RowItem>) cities);
                Collections.sort(cities, new Comparator<RowItem>() {
                    public int compare(RowItem s1, RowItem s2) {
                        return s1.getTitle().compareTo(s2.getTitle());
                    }
                });
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            try {
                TextView errorMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.routeTitel);
                errorMessage.setText(R.string.errorroute);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = getResources().getString(R.string.errorroute);
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        setTitle("Routen in" + " " + cityTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(RouteChooseActivity.this, RouteView.class);
        RowItem cities = (RowItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("stadt", citySave);
        b.putString("titel_stadt", cityTitle);
        b.putInt("route", cities.getID());
        b.putString("titel_route", cities.getTitle());
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

     @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("stadt", citySave);
    outState.getString("titel_stadt", cityTitle);
}

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
        // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
        citySave = savedInstanceState.getInt("stadt");
        Log.i("debug", "saved data: " + citySave);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

            Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
            citySave = b.getInt("stadt");
            cityTitle = b.getString("titel_stadt");

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("stadt", citySave);
        b.putString("titel_stadt", cityTitle);
        unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.Bild));
        System.gc();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("stadt", citySave);
        b.putString("titel_stadt", cityTitle);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.Bild));
        System.gc();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        citySave = b.getInt("stadt");
        cityTitle = b.getString("titel_stadt");
    }

    private void unbindDrawables(View view)
    {
        if (view.getBackground() != null)
        {
            view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup && !(view instanceof AdapterView))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++)
            {
                unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
            }
            ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.route, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_stadt:
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_stadt);
                Intent stadt = new Intent(RouteChooseActivity.this, StadtActivity.class);
                startActivity(stadt);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_help:
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);
                Intent help = new Intent(RouteChooseActivity.this, Help.class);
                startActivity(help);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_exit:
                moveTaskToBack(true);
                System.exit(0);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.cityknight.app/de.cityknight.app.RouteChooseActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at de.cityknight.app.RouteChooseActivity.onCreate(RouteChooseActivity.java:44)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check if Bundle b is null.

Comment: It could not be null, cause OnBackPressed is working.

Comment: Check this http://pastebin.com/N0fgWWYw and tell me what happend

Comment: Your NullPointerException is happening on line 44 of your RouteChooseActivity, where is the rest of the code?

Comment: I´ve added the whole code, but line 44 is citySave = b.getInt("stadt");

Comment: @user3586222 yes, the bundle seems null - but I don´t understand why?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Activity's `onCreate()` method, the Bundle will have this value: (from the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)))

> If the activity is being re-initialized after previously being shut
>   down then this Bundle contains the data it most recently supplied in
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle). Note: Otherwise it is null.

It goes the same for your `getIntent().getExtras()`. So you should check this value to avoid NullPointerException.

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if (b != null) {
  citySave = b.getInt("stadt");
  cityTitle = b.getString("titel_stadt");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try asap. If I understand you correctly, I´ve to set onRestoreInstanceState?

Comment: Edited answer. You have to check if the value is null or not.

Comment: thank you, what would be the else condition? I´ve tested: else {
            citySave = savedInstanceState.getInt("stadt");
            cityTitle = savedInstanceState.getString("titel_stadt");
        } but NullPointer. Without else condition NullPointer at citySave.equals...

Comment: If the Bundle is null, it means there is no data. So don't try to process the data at all as there will be a NullPointerException.

Comment: As you see, I´m a bloody beginner. Ok, I understand. How can I get the data?

Comment: First, try to **simplify** your example by sending only one data and try to get it on the other Activity. There is sooo much code on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer found on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17342137/3762248

"The "standard" behaviour for an android activity is, that a new instance of the activity is created, every time there is a new intent for this activity (see launchMode-docu here). Because of this your extras seem to be gone, if you call navigateUpTo.

In your case, I would advise to use

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

for your parent activity in your AndroidManifest.xml. This way you will return to your existing activity (as long as it is on the top of the back stack of your task). This way your extras will be preserved.

I too, do not understand why this is not mentioned in the Google doc you cite, as this seems the behaviour one expects if using up-navigation."